# include yaml file as a reference in another yaml file swagger

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to include a yaml file in my main yaml file I have used ref keyword but that one is not working, below is my yaml

main yaml file

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  $ref: /another.yaml

  version: "1"
  title: "test"
host: "localhost.com:8080"
basePath: "/test"
```

another.yaml

```
description: >
    ## test
      This is test
```

both file are in the same directory when I run it I cannot see the another.yaml contents in swagger ui. How can I achieve this, or is there any node module to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`info`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#infoObject) object does not support references. The only objects that support `$ref` are:

- `schema`
- path items
- operation parameters and path parameters
- individual responses in the `responses` section

When in doubt, refer to the [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

Comment: How can I include the description in base yaml file?